# ¿Qué es el número de búferes en cmd?

Tags: cmd

Estoy investigando un poco sobre la consola de Windows, para empezar a conocerla a fondo y he visto la sección "Historial de comandos".

En esta sección hay dos opciones tamaño del búfer, el cual si pones por ejemplo en 10 guardará hasta 10 comandos en el historial y la segunda opción, "Número de búferes".

¿Qué hace esto?

He probado de poner esta opción con valor 2 y el tamaño en 10 y aún así me guarda solo 10 comandos en el historial. Me gustaría saber como acceder a ese segundo búfer o para que sirve.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La mejor forma de explicar lo que has probado y lo que quieres es compartiendo código de lo que has probado y lo que esperas obtener :)

Comment: Realmente, no estaba probando código. Solo estoy mirando las opciones de configuración que trae CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **"tamaño del búfer"** indica cuántos comandos tienes disponibles para reutilizar cuando empleas las teclas arriba y abajo para recorrer entre comandos *históricos*.

El **"número de búferes"** representa cuántos procesos pueden tener sus propios búferes de comandos.

Comment: Entonces, ¿esto quiere decir que los búferes son como historiales para diferentes procesos?

Comment: Es una manera simple de verlo, sí.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he leído, la opción "Número de Búferes" especifica la cantidad de buffers que pueden tener procesos hijos del cmd antes de reciclar memoria de otros procesos.

> Tras ejecutar 5 comandos sus outputs están en sus respectivos buffers,
> al lanzar el 6º comando uno de los buffers anteriores será
> reutilizado para guardar el output de este.

Answer (score 0):

brevemente:

El "***Tamaño del búfer***" controla el número de líneas de comandos históricas disponibles cuando se utilizan las teclas de flecha arriba y flecha abajo para desplazarse por las líneas de comandos anteriores.

El "***Número de búferes***" controla cuántos procesos discretos pueden tener sus propios búferes de comandos individualizados antes de que los búferes se reciclen para procesos adicionales.